# Older rims, newer tires

Tags: tire, rims, compatibility

Can I put "new" 27 and half inch tires on "old" 27 inch rims?  Looking to 
save the trouble of finding out!

Comment: By "27 and half" I presume you mean "27 five" or "27.5", a size specific to mountain bikes, with an ISO rim diameter of 584.  This is NOT the same as a "27 inch" tire, which has an ISO rim diameter of 630.

Comment: (The only tire that will fits a 27" rim is another 27" tire.  This would be an "xx-630" ISO designation.)  http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html

Comment: Yes, I did mean 27.5 .  Thanks especially to Dan H. and Sheldon B.  The whole ISO rim diameter designation would seem to be next on the learning curve! Thanks again, great site!

Answer (score -2):

Have not seen 27 x 1/2 tires before but the old 27 x 1 1/4 rim probably will not care if the width is greater.  One question is whether the wider tire will clear your frame.

Comment: A 27 x 1/2 inch tire would be awfully narrow, don't you think?